# How do I make a persistent live USB of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: boot, live-usb, 16.04

I need the persistent live Ubuntu of preferably 16.04 because I need to rescue my whole encrypted HDD of 16.04 as discussed in the thread [How do I add myself back in sudo group in Encrypted HDD of 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/768916/25388)
I create here a new persistent Live Ubuntu 16.04 with some bugs described at the end with *Videonauth*.

1. `sudo apt-get install gksu debootstrap`
2. `gksudo gparted`. Make USB with `ext4` leaving only 1GB as free memory, and set 1GB for Linux Swap; Manage flags > only `boot`.
3. Prepare the OS by and run in the USB stick

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/stick
   sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/stick/
   sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 xenial /mnt/stick http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
   sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/stick/dev
   sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/stick/dev/pts
   sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/stick/sys
   sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/stick/proc
   sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/stick/etc/mtab
   sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/stick/etc/resolv.conf
   sudo chroot /mnt/stick/
   ```
4. Prompt looks like `root@masi-CM6340:/#`. Set locales.

   ```
   %locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8
   %dpkg-reconfigure locale
   dpkg-rekonfigure locales % two above commands cause a bug in gnome-terminal; choose here your locales and set environment en_US.UTF-8
   dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
   localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
   ```
5. `apt-get install linux-image-generic`. You get `/dev/sda [NotThisOne, your HDD], 2 /dev/sdb (31474 MB; ???) 2b - /dev/sdb1 (30398 MB; /)`. Choose `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb`. Choese here Linux kernel what you like. I keep Linux kernel 4.6 most stable which you can download as described at the end of the body.
6. `apt-get install vim wget`
7. `blkid`, copy to clipboard, `vim /etc/fstab`. Remove `sda` lines so only two `sdb` lines. Edit them to like `UUID="..." swap swap defaulst 0 0` and `UUID="..." / ext4 defaults 0 1`.
8. Paste the following to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted

   # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
   # newer versions of the distribution.
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
   # deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

   ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
   ## distribution.
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
   # deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

   ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
   ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
   ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
   ## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
   ## team.
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
   # deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
   # deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

   ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
   ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
   ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
   ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
   ## security team.
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
   # deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
   # deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

   ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
   ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
   ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
   ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
   ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
   deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   # deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

   ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
   ## 'partner' repository.
   ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
   ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
   deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
   deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
   # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
   # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
   # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
   ```
9. Do

   ```
   dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
   ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
   apt-get update
   % Comment this out if ubuntu-desktop is wanted
   apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
   % Comment out if ubuntu-server is wanted
   % apt-get install ubuntu-server
   adduser --home /home/masi masi
   ```
10. Add `masi` to the existing groups `usermod -aG adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare masi` where you can leave out `sambashare`.
11. Ignore drivers because USB stick not made for one PC.
12. For recovering the encrypted HDD, install the packages `apt-get ecryptfs-utils schroot testdisk` where `testdisk` for preparing discs and the other two for recovering the whole disc encrypted Ubuntu 16.04.
13. `sudo echo 'GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"' >> /etc/default/grub`; `update-grub`
14. Finalize the install. Do

    ```
    rm /sbin/initctl
    dpkg-divert --local --rename --remove /sbin/initctl
    ```

### Test your Installation of Persistent Live Ubuntu 16.04 [alpha]

1. Start your new Persistent Ubuntu. In terminal, do `sudo true`. If you get `Unable to resolve host * Connection refused`, do

   ```
   # https://askubuntu.com/q/59458/25388
   sudo vim /etc/hostname
   masi 

   sudo vim /etc/hosts 
   127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain masi
   [...]
   ```
2. Possible complication: Ubuntu starts in $(inittramfs)$. Do ...

### Result: USB starts up Ubuntu Desktop GUI and UI

- you can open LibreOffice, Firefox, ...
- `masi` is in sudo group; groups correct.
- Locales set correctly when `chroot` to stick.
- If you have a bug in gnome-terminal i.e. opening it in GUI, do `sudo dpkg-rekonfigure locales` again in TTY1. It resolves the case.

### Bugs which are reported to Videonauth

Always update-and-upgrade system in doing the tests: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

1. Ubuntu's Internet Browser. Launching it crashes the system. Mouse only works but no signal can be send to the TTY.
2. Firefox. Launching it gives a warning about [profile exists] so cannot open. Temporary fix `rm -r ~/.mozilla && rm -r ./.cache/mozilla` only for one session. The problem persists on every login. Better working fix: `sudo mv -v /home/masi /home/masi_backup`, `sudo mkdir -v /home/masi`, `sudo chown masi:masi /home/masi`, `sudo chmod 755 /home/masi` and `sudo reboot` because some ownerships of home-folder causes the bug. Run the command of  the [source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284451/16920) and you get the following differences
3. `/etc/hostname` fails to match `/etc/hosts` after some time
4. Sometimes, starts up to `(inittramsfs)`

Output of `vimdiff <(find /home/masi -printf "%P %u:%g %m\n" | sort) <(find /home/masi_backup -printf "%P %u:%g %m\n" | sort)`

```
%LHS-file
.bash_history masi:masi 600
.cache/compizconfig-1/animation.pb masi:masi 664
.cache/compizconfig-1/commands.pb masi:masi 664
.cache/compizconfig-1/compiztoolbox.pb masi:masi 664
% here many files not existing in the RHS

%RHS-file (fresh installation)
.bash_history root:root 600
.bash_logout masi:masi 664
.bashrc masi:masi 644
.cache root:root 700
```

where I do not understand which caused the bug.

### Upgrade to Linux Kernel 4.6

Do as instructed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786497/25388). There is an universal bug with resume/suspend in Linux kernel 4.4. Upgrading to 4.6 solves it and makes the system much better.

System: 14.04, 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.4 - 4.6

Comment: Have you every tried "Startup Disk Creator"?  It's a GUI app that will do exactly that, I think, using a standard liveCD ISO file.  Or UNetBootin, which will make all sorts of live USB disks without even downloading the ISO file first (but may not yet have 16.04).

Comment: @Masi Simply delete all the data on your current Ubuntu USB stick, and then follow the instructions for creating a new, persistent Ubuntu USB stick. If you have access to an Ubuntu ISO file (or can download one), that would be much easier than trying to "convert" an existing USB stick to persistent mode.

Comment: Can't you delete everything on your USB stick and then use Unetbootin or Startup Disk Creator to create a "new" persistent live USB? That would be much simpler than all those commands.

Comment: This sounds like a full install, that just happens to be on a USB, not a "live USB"...

Comment: @Xen2050 Yes and no. It is a full install. Live USB is something that allows you to test OS without installing it on your drive. This Live USB allows you to test it without installing it on your drive, but also use it on the USB itself. So it is a persistent live USB.

Comment: @masi you can delete point 14. added how to do this to my answer :)

Comment: @Masi That's stretching the generally used definition, see [Live USB on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) and contrast against the [Full Installation section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB#Full_Installation). Live USB's usually use a casper-rw file or partition to store changes, I expected to see how to encrypt a casper-rw here, but alas

Comment: My understanding is that in Ubuntu speak, a Live USB is the same as a Live CD, you can run but not save. A Persistent USB is a Live USB with a Persistent file or partition that allows saving the session, A Full install is an install to USB using the same methods as installing to internal HDD.

Comment: Startup Disk Creator from 16.04 no longer makes persistent USB's.

Comment: Sorry but Universal USB installer works perfect

Comment: Please, explain what you mean by perfect. Please, specify your environment. Please, explain your definition of the persistent environment.

Comment: Well perfect because is faster + 4 Gb in casper-rw

Comment: Please, define your environment. What is your *persistent*? Have you read the body?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make yourself a complete normal Ubuntu installation on an USB or an external HDD you can follow the procedure I describe here.

You want to start by doing some preparatory installations, you need `gksudo` which is in the package `gksu`, `schroot` and `debootstrap`. Those packages are not installed by default, so type in a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install gksu debootstrap schroot
```

Now you can start preparing your USB/HDD for installation by:

```
gksudo gparted
```

First you want to go to the `devices` menu and select `create partition table`, when asked for the type choose `msdos`. Now you should see an entry for unallocated space. Click on this and choose new and make it ext4 leaving only 1GB as free memory, then again click on the unallocated space entry and make it 1GB for Linux Swap. After this you apply your settings to the USB/HDD. Then right-click on the ext4 entry and choose `manage flags` and there you tick the check-mark on `boot` and leave.

Now you need to prepare your `chroot` environment to work in by doing the following commands one by one:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/stick
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/stick/
sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 xenial /mnt/stick http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/stick/dev
sudo mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/stick/dev/pts
sudo mount -t sysfs /sys /mnt/stick/sys
sudo mount -t proc /proc /mnt/stick/proc
sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/stick/etc/mtab
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/stick/etc/resolv.conf
sudo chroot /mnt/stick/
```

Your prompt should now look like this:

```
root@HOSTNAME:/#
```

Now you can begin your real installation process, start by setting the `locale` setting and the `keyboard-configuration` and installing the kernel.

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
dpkg-reconfigure locale
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8

apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

While this installation `GRUB` asks you for which device to be installed for. you will see a selection like this:

```
[ ]/dev/sda [NotThisOne, this is your HDD]
[ ]/dev/sdb (31474 MB; ???)
[ ]/dev/sdb1 (30398 MB; /)
```

Choose `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb` by moving to the respective field using the arrow keys and pressing <kbd>space</kbd> then finally hit return. Now after this installation is completed you can install your editor of choice, I do here as example `nano` and `vim`:

```
apt-get install nano vim
```

Now you can edit your `/etc/fstab` file, for this first get a list of the UUIDS in your system by:

```
blkid
```

This should give you an output like this:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="8f8f130f-e127-43b6-b797-8bfa3f1e1631" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="06bd4abe-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="8469c58b-b2bb-4551-b47d-c1a7d21e9ebd" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="06bd4abe-05"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="b08ab271-5619-479c-aa21-8aea7f4e6f3b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5872a1f8-01"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="c3309cee-731e-4030-93b9-f1d88c12c806" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="5872a1f8-02"
```

For easier editing you can copy the output from terminal by selecting it with your mouse and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then open your editor of choice by typing (I choose nano here for example):

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

You can paste the lines after you cleared out the files' contents by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Now delete the lines marked with `/dev/sda` which is most likely your HDD and change the other two lines around so they finally look like this:

```
UUID=18055918-6045-42e9-9492-66e3fd29c199 swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=69b5fb9c-774d-4d35-82f2-6a17faa446a1 / ext4 defaults 0 1
```

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to end your editing, choose `y` to save and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

As next you need to fill your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you can do so with copy and pasting the following block to your terminal and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> once.

```
cat > /etc/apt/sources.list << "EOF"
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
EOF
```

As for the final configuration packages must be installed which require starting services via Upstart, these must be disabled in the `chroot` temporarily:

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

Now run an update and you can install either `ubuntu-server` or `ubuntu-desktop` or even both as long you do server before desktop.

```
apt-get update
# Comment this out if ubuntu-desktop is not wanted
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
# remove comment if ubuntu-server is wanted
# apt-get install ubuntu-server
```

and finally add your user and put him into the proper groups:

```
adduser --home /home/<username> <username>

usermod -aG adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,plugdev,lpadmin,sambashare <username>
```

Where you can leave out sambashare if it gives you errors. Check if the group settings are correct by:

```
less /etc/group
```

You should see for each group listed in the above `usermod` command and entry like this (example sudo):

```
sudo:x:27:<username>
```

If not add the groups one by one with the above `usermod` command. Now it is time to maybe install drivers and useful tools, I list here only a few for your case necessary ones.

```
apt-get ecryptfs-utils testdisk schroot
```

To make GRUB only recognize your stick as OS and not adding the System you have build the stick on do:

```
echo 'GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"' >> /etc/default/grub
update-grub
```

Finalize the install by:

```
rm /sbin/initctl
dpkg-divert --local --rename --remove /sbin/initctl
```

Now you can reboot onto your USB and have a fully installed Ubuntu system to work with. If you run into the trouble of not being able to start the terminal which seems to be related to a bug in `gnome-terminal` you can check in TTY (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> and login with your username and password) the content of `/var/log/syslog` if it contains lines like this:

```
May 7 22:30:00 NEXUS-TWO org.gnome.Terminal[1432]: Non UTF-8 locale (ISO-8859-1) is not supported!
```

To fix this it seem to be enough to execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` within TTY and choosing explicitly UTF-8. or set the language and so on within the GUIs settings. Afterwards reboot.

Comment: Is this very different from what the automatic installer (ubiquity?) does? I'm not sure if the OP is using the term "*live*" correctly...

Comment: I dont know `ubiquity`yet, this answer is the result of a lengthly chat conversation with the OP.

Comment: The default Ubuntu installer, I think is still [Ubuquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquity_%28software%29)

Comment: should work tho

Comment: @Videonauth Please, see the body. Some new cases found. How should the `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` set up? - - They started to fail in my system after some time, and now in `(inittramfs)`.

Comment: `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`you can set from the settings, and they are for sure not the cause for you booting into initramfs.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some details. (Someone else should write a more independent review about the pros and cons.)

- **Cloning: dd** is a very powerful but also very dangerous tool, often nicknamed 'disk destroyer' or 'data destroyer'. dd is used to **clone** an iso file to a USB pendrive. When creating live-only USB boot drives, **mkusb** 'wraps a safety belt around dd'. This method works for all hybrid iso files, and most modern linux distros provide this kind of iso files. The new **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** in 16.04 LTS uses the cloning method too.
- Many other tools **extract** the content of the iso file to a FAT32 partition, for example **Rufus** and **Unetbootin**. (Rufus has also a cloning `dd` mode.)
- **mkusb is a linux tool**. It does not work in Windows.

  Prepare:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa
  sudo apt update
  ```

  Install mkusb:

  ```
  sudo apt install mkusb
  ```
- **mkusb is a bash script**, that uses several standard tools, available in most linux distros. mkusb uses **zenity** for a graphical user interface when available.
- **mkusb-nox** (No X) works in ***text mode***, for example in Ubuntu Server. **mkusb-dus** (actually **dus**) can work in text mode too with **dialog** text mode menus or with a plain text interface. In a pure text mode system (for example Ubuntu Server) you should install the package **dus** and/or **mkusb-nox**, not the whole package **mkusb**,

  ```
  sudo apt install dus mkusb-nox
  ```
- Some of the other tools consist of **compiled code**.
- mkusb can create **persistent live systems for Debian and Ubuntu**. These systems are booted via grub2, and the iso file is cloned to a separate partition. A **casper-rw partition** will be created for persistence and a **usbdata partition** will be created for storing data and sharing data with computers running Windows. These persistent live systems can boot in UEFI and BIOS mode.
- mkusb-nox and mkusb-dus can create a **USB installer for Windows 7-11** via extraction. It uses the grub-pc package to install grub2, which makes the USB pendrive boot in BIOS mode. This system can boot in UEFI and BIOS mode.
- mkusb does *not* create multi-boot USB drives. There are other tools for that purpose.
- mkusb can also **wipe confusing data** and/or **restore a USB boot drive to a standard storage device** with an MSDOS partition table and a FAT32 file system.

See the following links if you want more details,

- [mkUSB-quick-start-manual](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf)
- [mkusb-Persistent live systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Persistent_live_systems)

Comment: It would be great to get more pieces of information about the limitations of `mkusb`.

Comment: Please ask, and I will reply. Or even better, try it, and ask if something does not work :-)

Answer (score 4):

Wow that sounds complex, **mkusb** can do a Live Persistent install much faster than I can read either procedure above. They also sound like Full installs not Persistent Live installs. A persistent install uses a casper-rw file or partition. It is called persistent install because the word persistent in the boot file is used to activate persistence.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb for details of **mkusb**.

A USB drive made with mkusb also has no problem doing a Full install to HDD or USB.

Comment: It seems to be also supported in Debian.

Comment: It also works making a petty good base for Puppy Tahr among other O/S's

Comment: It would be nice to get a review about the differences about the tool with the other method. Pros and cons.

Comment: A good guide to making persistent pendrives using mkusb: http://askubuntu.com/questions/772744/how-to-make-a-live-usb-persistent/815493#815493

Comment: On this page is quick install guide edited by mkusb's creator Sudodus. Note that mkusb is evolving rapidly and is at version 11.1.9 at this time, It may also be forking into a more direct installer named dus.

Comment: I feel the guide is a stub. I would like to get a review about the features.

Comment: There is an extensive documentation at the Ubuntu help pages, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb, but a review should be written by someone else ...