# Why Grub does not Recognize Two USB sticks in 16.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

I have two persistent live USB sticks made as described in the thread [How to Make Persistent Live Ubuntu of 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/768970/25388) on the Computer. It just recognises one USB boot option. It seems to boot the smaller number USB order always. However, I would like to decide which USB stick to boot from i.e. to decide the highest priority at Grub. 
The challenge can be limited to hardware limitations of the USB bus itself

- tested on old firmware/old Bios of Dell PC which has no Hot Plug Support
- new firmware/new Bios of Lenovo PC 2013 with Hot Plug Support ...

---

How can you decide which USB stick to boot from in Grub of Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a computer which has new Bios that is graphical. I could not get the prioritizing work with older PCs having the textual Bios. However, the prioritizing works in the newer Bioses. Probably, just Grub2 is enough.