# How is Ubuntu 16.04's Whole-Media Encryption done?

Tags: 16.04, encryption

I would like to have an Encrypted whole-media Persistent Live USB Ubuntu 16.04. I can create a persistent live Ubuntu 16.04 as described in the thread [How to Make Persistent Live Ubuntu of 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/768970/25388)
However, I would like to have a whole-media encrypted device. 
I think I can make such a device when I understand better how the current whole-media encryption of the installation is done.

Current status: trying to understand how it is done in Debian 7 and 8.

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6