# How to Copy System With Systemback of Persistent Live Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, backup, systemback

System: Dell customer PC Studio XPS 8100 PC, i5 2009, 16 GB; which uses Legacy boot. Active on [Persistent Live Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/768970/25388). SATA connection to HD-500GB which has System of Ubuntu 16.04 which I want copy. I have USB-3.0 connection to my backup-drive (2.0 TB).

```
% HD which I want to copy
/dev/sda 465.76 GiB 
/dev/sda1 449.83 GiB     ext4
/dev/sda2 15.93 GiB
/dev/sda5 15.93 GiB
% Backup HD
/dev/sdg 1.82 TiB 
/dev/sdg1 1.82 TiB /media/masi/ntfs... ntfs
% Persistent Live Ubuntu 16.04
/dev/sdh 14.9 GiB
/dev/sdh1 14.9 GiB vfat
```

I do

```
gksudo systemback 
"System copy"
Select /dev/sda1 > unmount
```

but now it offers only options like `!Delete!`, `Mount point:`, `Filesystem:`, `Format yes/no` and inactive `Next` button. 
Question about the problem in the project site [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/systemback/+question/293877).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot easily. Use simply `tar czf` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/788272/25388). Differential tool is `Deja-dup` but it is unstable with many filesystems and even with core-systems.