# How to Start Persistent Ubuntu 16.04 in Macbook?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, live-usb, macbook

I am trying to find a way to run my Macbook Air 2013-mid from the external media (usb) containing Persistent Ubuntu 16.06, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768970/how-to-make-persistent-live-ubuntu-of-16-04) for the creation of the stick:

1. Fixing the EFI partition
2. Update filesystem table
3. Installing GRUB

but the problem is that I cannot run any live system on Macbook Air. I cannot get the SSD out without Apple service. 
The following is the process about how I would proceed after successfully managing to mount OS X SSD in any system.

### Fixing the EFI partion in Macbook Air 2013-mid

The system has UEFI (some firmware [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1689?locale=en_US)), but OSX expects EFI bootloader be formatted as HFS+ (see *Fixnig the EFI partition* [here](http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/)).
Problem is that I cannot run live media in Macbook air and do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:detly/mactel-utils
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mactel-boot hfsprogs gdisk grub-efi-amd64
mount % see the sd[]; here sd1
sudo umount /dev/sda1 
sudo gdisk /dev/sda % delete VFAT, create HFS+
% delete EF00 partion there with `d`
% create HFS+ partion there with `n`
% enter filesystem option `AF00`
% write with `w`
% now you have unformatted HFS+ so format it with
sudo mkfs.hfsplus /dev/sda1 -v Ubuntu
```

### Updating filesystem table

```
sudoedit /etc/fstab
sudo bash -c 'echo $(blkid -o export -s UUID /dev/sda1) /boot/efi auto defaults 0 0 >> /etc/fstab'
sudo mount /boot/efi % testing
```

### Installing GRUB

```
sudo mkdir -p "/boot/efi/EFI/$(lsb_release -ds)/"
%% BUG in GRUB but two following lines can soon be omitted
sudo bash -c 'echo "This file is required for booting" > "/boot/efi/EFI/$(lsb_release -ds)/mach_kernel"'
sudo bash -c 'echo "This file is required for booting" > /boot/efi/mach_kernel'
sudo grub-install --target x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id="$(lsb_release -ds)"
sudo hfs-bless "/boot/efi/EFI/$(lsb_release -ds)/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi"
```

### Boot as UEFI

To setup EFI boot in Mac, is described [here](https://glandium.org/blog/?p=2830) about *https://glandium.org/blog/?p=2830* in the same HD as your Mac installation.
This setup is different from booting from the live Ubuntu. 
I have not managed to do this. TODO

This can be the solution to the problem, see the thread [here](http://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/) about *UBUNTU + MAC: PURE EFI BOOT*.

---

How can you Mount OS X SSD in Live Ubuntu?

How can you Start Persistent Ubuntu 16.04 in Macbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQIaDO9nR6Y

I've seen plenty of positive comments, so I think that video should work!

Comment: Actually, I did exactly what was in the video with Macbook Air 2013-mid now. I just have problem with my wifi.

Comment: Now, I have a problem that my Ubuntu installation replaced the refind bootloader. Now, I have just Grub. I cannot read my OS X with my Ubuntu. I am not sure how equivalent Linux recovery mode to OS X's one.