# How to Install TWRP with 16.04 for Phone?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, android, adb

I am trying to install Cyanogenmod 13 in Oneplus 2 but I cannot get TWRP flashed in the phone because I cannot get `adb` work as expected with Ubuntu 16.04 in common Ubuntu, Persistent Live Ubuntu and Live Ubuntu.

1. Common Ubuntu

   The command `adb devices` and `fastboot devices` returns nothing, although it should not, since my Android phone is in the developer mode with enabled `fastboot`. 
   Work flow

   ```
   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ wget -O - https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz | tar -zxvf - adb
   --2016-08-15 17:16:09--  https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz
   Resolving skia.googlesource.com (skia.googlesource.com)... 74.125.136.82, 2a00:1450:4013:c01::52
   Connecting to skia.googlesource.com (skia.googlesource.com)|74.125.136.82|:443... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
   Length: unspecified [application/x-gzip]
   Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

   -                   [<=>   ]       0  --.-KB/s               adb
   -                        [        <=>            ]   1.31M  70.0KB/s    in 19s     

   2016-08-15 17:16:29 (70.0 KB/s) - written to stdout [1374340]

   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ sudo mv adb /usr/bin/adb
   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ adb version
   Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ adb devices
   List of devices attached 

   masi@masi:~/Downloads$ sudo adb devices
   List of devices attached
   ```

   I think the `adb` version works at least in 14.04 but not now with 16.04.

   Inspecting with `lsusb` shows that the device is detected in Ubuntu as `Bus 001 Device 050: ID 2a70:f003`.

   Settings where I already authorized USB debugging

   [image]

   I do when `masi` is in the group `plugdev` but still unsuccessful result

   ```
   # OrganicMarble
   sudo touch /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

   masi@masi:/$ sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 

   masi@masi:~$ groups masi
   masi : masi adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev staff lpadmin sambashare

   masi@masi:/$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a70", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

   masi@masi:/$ sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

   masi@masi:/$ sudo adb devices
   * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
   * daemon started successfully *

   List of devices attached 

   masi@masi:/$ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   ```
2. Persistent Live Ubuntu

   Fails with bugs in `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`, not related to this case but reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/768970/25388)
3. Live Ubuntu 16.04

   This attempt fails in trying to get `adb to work`

   ```
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ wget -O - https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz | tar -zxvf - adb
   --2016-08-15 17:16:09--  https://skia.googlesource.com/skia/+archive/cd048d18e0b81338c1a04b9749a00444597df394/platform_tools/android/bin/linux.tar.gz
   Resolving skia.googlesource.com (skia.googlesource.com)... 74.125.136.82, 2a00:1450:4013:c01::52
   Connecting to skia.googlesource.com (skia.googlesource.com)|74.125.136.82|:443... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
   Length: unspecified [application/x-gzip]
   Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

   -                   [<=>   ]       0  --.-KB/s               adb
   -                        [        <=>            ]   1.31M  70.0KB/s    in 19s     

   2016-08-15 17:16:29 (70.0 KB/s) - written to stdout [1374340]

   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mv adb /usr/bin/adb
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
   ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ adb version
   bash: /usr/bin/adb: No such file or directory
   ```

Ubuntu: 16.04
Linux kernel 4.6
Phone: Oneplus 2
Phone settings: Oxygen OS 3.20, Developer mode, `fastboot` on

Comment: Is adb enabled in your phone/oxygen OS developer settings?

Comment: On the phone, did you already authorize the computer to do USB debugging? You would have received a prompt.

Comment: I don't run `adb` with `sudo`.  Don't know if that matters or not.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I does not matter if you run it with or without sudo - - same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you do not get anything from `adb devices` is that your phone is not in the fastboot mode. So put your phone there and try again.

Shortly, here the work flow without rooting your phone. Do where `recovery.img` is the renamed TWRP image but has to be renamed like that

1. Enable Developer mode in your phone; enable smart bootloader and the other setting in Developer settings
2. Start your phone in `fastboot`; power + volume up; press so long as your phone vibrates
3. `fastboot devices` should return the device id; `fastboot oem unlock` and phone phone reboots
4. Again to `fastboot` and run `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`
5. Go now to the recovery mode by Power + volume down
6. Wipe everything else except internal data
7. Install and flash with Switch_to_OOS3_H2OSMM.zip such that you can flash your OO Rom
8. Flash now with Cyanogenmod Rom and Pico Gapps (Arm64) - only for Google Play Store
9. Wipe Cache/dalvik

Sources

1. https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/24-06-2016-oneplus-2-how-to-unlock-bootloader-flash-twrp-root-nandroid-efs-backup-and-more.345478/
2. http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-2/development/6-0-x-cyanogenmod-13-oneplus-2-t3292436/page769

Systems: Ubuntu 16.04, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention it, so it's possible that you didn't update `/etc/udev/rules.d/51‌​-android.rules` to include your device.

If this file doesn't exist, create it, and add a line for each device using this format.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

(all entries are just as written except for idVendor.  Look that up in [this table](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#VendorIds).)

Once your file is complete, then execute

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

If all else is well, you should be able to connect using adb.

Comment: If your device manufacturer isn't in the table (mine wasn't) try using the string found after ID in the output from `lsusb` - in your case `2a70`

Comment: You should be a member of group `plugdev`, but check and make sure by typing in a terminal `groups your-userid`.

Comment: You have performed all the steps that I did to get mine working, so something else must be going on :(

Comment: I have it working both on 14.04 and 16.04 machines.  It's been a while, but I think on 16.04 I installed from the repo.  You have to have 1.0.32 for it to work, but I saw in your question that you do have that.