# Hostname on a usb os

Tags: usb, debootstrap

I installed xubuntu-core on a usb (with `debootstrap`) while following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768970/how-to-make-persistent-live-ubuntu-of-16-04).

It's all successful but it still has the hostname of the laptop it was installed through. That bumps me the error `sudo: unable to resolve host <UnwantedLaptopHostname>` whenever I sudo, and it's generally irritating.

Can anyone please help me with sorting things out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an entry for `UnwantedLaptopHostname` to `/etc/hosts` or you DNS server, or change `/etc/hostname` to a name that is known by `/etc/hosts` or you DNS.