# Need to make a portable Ubuntu with only 1 pendrive

Tags: boot, usb-drive

I have been using Ubuntu for a while. I find it very convenient to plug my pendrive into any computer and then use it like my own.
Installing Ubuntu on a pen drive required 2 pen drives..i was wondering if there was a better way, using just 1 pen drive (for eg: make a bootable virtual disc and then run that on a VM and use that to install it on the pen drive.
Is this possible? Can someone direct me to a place where i can find the steps?

Thank u!

Comment: If your system uses `grub` (boot loader), you can make that boot an ISO thus it's only one pen-drive needed (we don't know if you are using `grub`). You can also run a `vm` from an ISO allowing it to write to a pen-drive (this requires setup on your HOST which you haven't told us what it is).  Yes it's possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a live Ubuntu 18.04 USB with a persistent storage of more than 4GB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051543/how-to-make-a-live-ubuntu-18-04-usb-with-a-persistent-storage-of-more-than-4gb)

Comment: For installing to pendrive it was booted from See https://askubuntu.com/questions/855696/can-a-persistent-ubuntu-install-be-made-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from and https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from

Comment: Basically if you boot toram the boot USB can be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

### If you have a Live Ubuntu USB you can boot it **toram**.

For UNetbootin press tab key at start menu and type a space and toram.
For other installers press shift and then F6 when booting, type a space and toram.

Once booted you can then install Ubuntu to the existing USB drive from the RAM session.

Backup the USB before proceeding.

Installing from VM also works but you need to install from a VM of the ISO image and not the VM of an installed system, (which has no installer).