# Why is casper-rw full on first start on persistent linux?

Tags: live-usb, persistence, rufus

I used Rufus on Windows 10 for making a persistent linux (Ubuntu 19.10) on a 64GB SSD. I chose 40GB for the persistent partition and after the boot it always ask 'Try Linux on CD or Install it?'. I went for trying it out, because my goal is to only have it on my SSD, to be portable. 
My problem is that the casper-rw is 40GB but 38GB is used. Is this normal?
Where should I install my programs? Or 64GB is not enough?
I want to use it for developing.

Comment: Persistence by Rufus is experimental, and there is a bug. You can create a persistent live drive according to the following link: [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10) -- But if you want to use Ubuntu for development it might be better to get a real installed system, maybe installed into a fast USB 3 pendrive, but better into an SSD in an external box or via a USB to SATA or m2 adapter.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu in an external drive (that is independent of the internal drive) according to this link: [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Comment: Did you try to do a software update? This can quickly fill a casper-rw file or partition. You can create a reliable **mkusb** persistent install to the SSD using this method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/855696/can-a-persistent-ubuntu-install-be-made-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from