# Live boot, casper-rw issue

Tags: live-usb, rufus

I created a live bootable USB for Ubuntu through Rufus 3.14 on Windows 10.
I used the persistent storage available there and after booting into Ubuntu, I see a disk partition casper-rw present but I am unable to store anything there or interact with it. Do I need to mount it or do anything else to make it usable?

Comment: There [were](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1877222) some bugs related to casper mounts from iso, but rufus mounts from squashfs directly, so you shouldn't be affected. If you are... file some other bug report!

Answer (score 2):

### casper-rw overlay

Casper-rw is an overlay of the read only Ubuntu filesystem. It is where new "Persistent" programs and data is stored.

The partition file system is ext4 which is not accessible to Windows.

When using the USB in Windows as a data storage device, you can store date in the root partition. (the only partition you can see in Windows). It is best to store the Windows data in it's own folder.

When booted from the USB the Windows date can be accessed **read only** from the cdrom folder.

If you want to use a USB for data and persistent Ubuntu create it using **mkusb** see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb.

Mkusb can create a Persistent USB that has an option for a NTFS data partition that is accessible to Windows and Linux.

Mkusb can install to the same drive it was booted on: [Can a Persistent Ubuntu install be made to the pendrive it was booted from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855696/can-a-persistent-ubuntu-install-be-made-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from)

An option to a Persistent USB is to create a Full install USB, See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1350124/43926

Answer (score 2):

If you created the persistent partition in Rufus, and are using a recent ISO of Ubuntu, the persistent partition should **already** be usable, without you needing to do anything.

Just try to create a file or folder on your desktop and reboot.
If you see the file/folder after your reboot, it means that your persistent storage **is** working. You don't have to worry about whether Ubuntu says that there exists a `casper-rw` partition, because that's just Ubuntu reporting what exists on the media.

Answer (score 0):

LiveCD is a temp OS，you need to install Ubuntu to USB or other storage media if you want to use persistent storage.

Comment: So, I cannot use the casper-rw partition until I install the OS somewhere?

Comment: Maybe you can create a casper-rw, and mount it with loop type when you create live bootable USB.