# how to recover lost USB capacity?

Tags: fdisk, parted

I used dd to write the image to my flash drive (64M image). Real capacity of USB is 2G
Works great.
But when I tried to write Xubuntu img on it. There is no free space.
I already tried fdisk, parted and others, but there is no result.

Please, help me.
What may I do to recover USB capacity?

ps I can use only cli

Comment: the best way use `testdisk`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capacity of pen drive shown is less than the actual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611325/capacity-of-pen-drive-shown-is-less-than-the-actual)

Answer (score 1):

That's right; when you use [dd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dd.1.html) to image a USB drive, the source file is all you get.  You will need to use [fdisk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fdisk.8.html) or [parted](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/parted.8.html) to delete the filesystem on the USB (erasing what you put there before) then create a FAT or FAT32 partition to make all the space usable.

Illustrations of [how to use fdisk in general are shown here](https://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/); examples of fdisk and parted [are shown here](https://www.tecmint.com/linux-partition-managers/).

Comment: is a way without gui? I  can use only cli

Comment: CLI apps to do that are linked in the revised answer.